# Synonym Request: [smtp] -> [email]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I have [a review request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/111395/46291) that pertains specifically to SMTP behaviour and would like it tagged as such so as to be unambiguous and searchable. However, I have no objection to such a tag deferring to [email](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) as the predominant family descriptor.

Answer (score 6):

I've now suggested a synonym proposal [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/email/synonyms) for the community to vote on.  If it reaches 4 votes, it'll take effect.  But if it reaches -2, it'll be canceled.

Comment: What is the difference between SMTP and EMAIL?  I actually prefer the former as it is more specific, formalized, etc.

Comment: @HostileFork SMTP refers to a specific protocol to send e-mail. E-mail refers to e-mails in general. I believe the broader tag email is better here.

Comment: Wouldn't that be analogous to merging [http] -> [web], or [ftp] -> [file-system]? Perhaps something to consider...

Comment: Interesting, mods can actually *propose* instead of just *create* a synonym? Never knew that...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yes.  Proposal is done on the master tag's page, whereas creation is done on the main tag synonyms page.